# How to Get child of Parent in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table below. I want to write mySql Query that can return all the children against the parent Id. i.e. against 0 it should return (1,2,3,4) and against 1 it should return (3,4).

I am able to do this recursive call in SQL server using "with" clause, but i want to do this same thing in MySQL.

ParentId     GroupID
0         |       0
0         |       1
0         |       2
1         |       3
3         |       4

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: What are 1,2,3,4?  are they groupId values ... from example expected output is not clear.

Comment: Have you tried anything? I'm not sure I fully understand if you do a select against parentid = 0 wouldn't it return 0,1,2 and if you select against 1 it would return 3? Or do you want to do recursive selects?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136041/sql-tree-like-query-most-parent-group

Comment: Take look at this book excerpt: http://media.pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/trees.pdf

Comment: I want recursive select ... I am able to do this in SQL server using "With" clause, but i am not able to do it in mysql.

Comment: I believe it is possible to be done with stored procedure (program) and `cursor` (loop).

Answer (score 0):

If this is an arbitrary depth hierarchy (you want ancestor instead of parent), then you can't do this directly in SQL. Google for "sql hierarchical queries" to find some possible workarounds.