# How to count items per category?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I want to make a filtering of products on a site.
Something  like this:

```
Department
- lassics (13,395)
- Literary (111,399)
- History (68,606)
...

Format
- HTML (3,637)
- PDF (8)
- Audio CD (443)
...

Language
- English (227,175)
- German (10,843)
- French (10,488)
...
```

How to count products per category? A separate SQL-query for each category would be too slow because there are too many products and categories. I suggest caching is not an option too.

Maybe it makes sense to use  MySQL EXPLAIN queries (though it not always provide adequate information)? Or maybe using sphinx search engine for counting?...  What is the best way to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: check related post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136041/sql-tree-like-query-most-parent-group

Answer (score 14):

Try:

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) as count FROM table GROUP BY category
```

The response should be all the different `category` values, and the number of occurrences of each.

Comment: @fahim has the best answer, one should always avoid using ```(*)``` when it can be avoided.

Answer (score 10):

How about this

```
SELECT field1, count(1) as Total
FROM myTable
GROUP BY field1
```

Comment: This is the best practice. Alwasy avoid using ```(*)```  if you can do something else

Answer (score 5):

Use `COUNT()` with the [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) to group them together by category

Comment: I know SQL syntax. It is not the case.  I'm worried about performance. There will be nearly 500 000 items and the queries will be rather heavy with many parameters so it will take a lot of time for counting