# MySQL a query from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables created with SQL. The first one has an unique id and a name of a provider. The second one has a product name, the amount of that product and the id of the provider.
I need a query that gives me the name of each provider and the total sum of the product amount that they have.

Ex:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS provider  
(id int unique auto_increment primary key,  
name char(50));  

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product  
(id int unique auto_increment primary key,  
name char(30),  
provider_id int NOT NULL,  
amount int NOT NULL);  

Provider: (id, name)  
1 Mike  
2 Peter  
3 John

Product: (id, name, provider_id, amount)  
1 RedCar 1 100  
2 BlueCar 1 50  
3 RedCar 3 35  
4 OrangeCar 2 500  
5 GreenCar 3 250  

Query:  
Mike 150  
Peter 500  
John 285
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687773/how-to-count-items-per-category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a simple `LEFT JOIN` with `GROUP BY` aggregation. `LEFT JOIN` will ensure to account for a provider even if he/she does not have any product.

[`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function is used to calculate the sum of `amount` for a specific `provider`. We can use [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to handle `NULL` values. `SUM()` will return `NULL` for the cases when there is no product for a provider.

```
SELECT 
  pvd.id, 
  pvd.name, 
  COALESCE(SUM(pdt.amount),0) AS total_amount
FROM Provider AS pvd
LEFT JOIN Product AS pdt 
  ON pdt.provider_id = pvd.id
GROUP BY pvd.id, pvd.name
```

**P.S.** It is advisable to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) in case of multi-table queries, for code clarity (readability) and avoiding ambiguous behaviour.

**P.P.S.** If you don't want to list the provider with no products; you can change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`, and get rid of the `COALESCE()` function usage as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL query that gives result as per you want.

```
SELECT pr.name,SUM(p.amount) as total_amount FROM `provider` pr LEFT JOIN `product` p ON p.provider_id = pr.id where 1 GROUP BY pr.id
```